# Is there a way to add new routes in a helper method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have many routes and it's taking a long time to boot up the app. I want to add routes to a helper method and call it when I need it. Is this possible?

I tried adding something like this to the application_helper.rb file:

```
def add_new_routes
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get "/something" => "something#index"
  end
end
```

While that made the /something route work, it also made the regular routes from the routes.rb unusable. Is there a way to add routes correctly through a helper file while also keeping the original routes?

Comment: I have this sneaking suspicion that your routes isn't what's slowing down your application...

Comment: I have over a thousand routes on an app and removing 90% of it for example gives me a 90% boost. I'm not sure if there's an underlying issue but it does make my app much faster if I remove the routes.

Comment: So let's start with the elephant in the room:  **you have over a thousand routes in a Rails app.**  Have you considered either breaking those out into a few dozen Rails apps, or moving to a language which isn't interpreted?

Comment: I did do that initially by breaking down into multiple apps but it became a maintenance headache. Everything for now works fine except for the large routes.rb file. The app works fine. It's just the routes.rb file that's making the boot up time slower and it's also using a lot of memory.

Comment: I doubt that there is such a direct correlation between number of routes and the duration it takes to boot the application. Processing the `roues.rb` is only a small part of the whole process.

Comment: I'm not exactly seeing a clean way out of this; either there's a maintenance issue with dealing with over a thousand routes scattered across multiple applications, or there's a performance issue when having them all in one.  Again, I'm not entirely convinced that this is the main issue.  Have you profiled your application to definitively prove that this is the issue?

Comment: I suggest a simple test to understand if the pure size of the `routes.rb` really causes this problem: Generate a new empty Rails project and messure its boot time. Then copy only your `routes.rb` into that app and messure boot time again. This should be possible, since in theory a `routes.rb` should have zero or a low number of external dependencies. If it does not work, look closely at the missing external dependencies that let this fail.

Comment: There may be an underlying issue like a method that I'm using in the routes.rb that's causing the long delay. I'll start checking. There's actually quite more than 1000 routes because I have loops that create extra routes. For example if you add something like this to the routes.rb file for a Rails app: 200000.times { get "/something" => "something#index" }, you'll notice the long delay.

Comment: Spickermann, great idea. I just did that and the large routes.rb is what's causing the slow boot time. The boot time and memory that it takes are the only issues I currently have. Otherwise the app works just fine so this is not a complete disaster if I can't get it to boot faster. I'm assuming there's no way to create route on the fly in a helper method?

Comment: It feels wrong to me to generate routes in loops. I would like to understand the problem you try to solve. What to you try to achieve? Can you post an example of such a loop?

Comment: A looped route would be something like this: 

%w{recipes cuisines meals}.each do |plural_name| 
    get plural_name => "#{plural_name}#index"
    get "#{plural_name}/completed" => "completed_#{plural_name}#index"
end

Something like that. The routes are a lot more complex though so I can't combine them into a generic controller/routes.

Comment: So you are telling us, that your app has 200.000 unique controller#actions?

Comment: I really have no idea. There are over 1000 lines of code in my routes.rb file but a lot of loops so there are many many routes. There aren't nearly as many controllers/actions though because the routes use many of the same controllers/actions.

Comment: If there are multiple routes pointing to the same controller and action please consider refactor the routes to accept dynamic parameters in controller actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible, but please, for the love of god, read all those comments about how the problem is NOT your routes.

With this technique, all your routes will have to be reloaded when you remove (disable) a routeset.

Stick this somewhere that will be loaded when the application is started.

```
class DynamicallyCreatedRouteset
  def self.load
    self.create_routes! if @routeset_enabled
  end

  def self.enable!
    return true if @routeset_enabled
    @routeset_enabled = true
    self.load
  end

  def self.disable!
    return false unless @routeset_enabled
    @routeset_enabled = false
    self.reload_routes!
  end

  def self.reload_routes!
    RailsAppName::Application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end

  def self.create_routes!
    # a class derives this and implements their own
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class MyRouteSet < DynamicallyCreatedRouteset
  def self.create_routes!
    RailsAppName::Application.routes.draw do
      get '/someroute'
      post '/etc....'
    end
  end
end

class MyOtherRouteSet < DynamicallyCreatedRouteset
  def self.create_routes!
    RailsAppName::Application.routes.draw do
      get '/anotherroute'
      post '/etc....'
    end
  end
end
```

in your config/routes.rb, inside the `RailsAppName::Application.routes.draw` block

```
# Have load for every custom routeset you defined.
MyRouteSet.load
MyOtherRouteSet.load
```

Outside of the `routes.draw` block, you can put `MyRouteSet.enable!` for dynamically enabled routes that should be enabled at startup.

and in a helper

```
def my_route_helper
  MyRouteSet.enable!
end

def disable_my_route_set
  MyRouteSet.disable!
end

def my_other_route_helper
  MyOtherRouteSet.enable!
end

# etc....
```

Note that all dynamically enabled routes will be disabled by default, as `@routeset_enabled` will be nil. If you want some routes enabled by default you'll need to call `MyRouteSet.enable!` after `routes.draw`.

Also note that this technique will have the same effect of reloading your entire route table when a routeset is disabled which may actually make your app too slow in certain cases as the whole route table is redrawn. For example if the disable helper is called as part of a controller action, and if your routes are really THAT slow, it may possibly lead to connection timeouts and such. Or it can lead to fun DoS attack (fun for the attacker, not for you) in which someone calls the enable and disable action repeatedly.

Comment: Really appreciate this Illya!! Thank you :) I'll try it now.

Comment: Actually, if youre only mostly concerned about adding and not removing them, theres a slight refactor that you could that actually make it less slow. Give me a few minutes to update this answer.

Comment: OK see the updated answer. Now it won't redraw the entire route table unless a routeset is disabled. Which should actually give you a startup performance benefit. Also note that I completely ad-libbed this code at 2 AM with a severe sleep defecit and haven't tested it. If it acts weird, it's probably a syntax issue or something, but still you're on your own

Comment: Sweet! It's working for me now :) Finally got it to work because of your amazing help. You're awesome Ilya. Thank you Ilya!! :)